# Missing records when doing pagination with LINQ and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table like below which contains a lot of data and would like to get chunk by chunk:

**ProcessData**

```
ProcessDataId      ProcessId       IsProcessed
----------------------------------------------
1                  100              0
2                  100              0
3                  100              0
4                  100              0
5                  100              0
.
.
167                100              0
```

I am getting 50 data at a time, processing it and updating `IsProcessed` value to 1 in the database. Now what is happening is I am able to process 150 data but I am not getting the last 17 records in the while loop because of this below call :

```
// update IsProcessed column in database for 50 records
await BulkUpdateProcessData(processDataChunk);
```

When I call '`BulkUpdateProcessData`' method after the while loop and update all the 167 records at the end then it works fine but I don't want to hold all the data in the memory for a long and then update all the data at the end.

Code:

```
var getUnProcessedDataQuery = context.ProcessData.Where(p=>p.ProcessId==100 && !IsProcessed).OrderBy(p=>p.ProcessDataId);

int unProcessedDataCount = getUnProcessedDataQuery.Count();

int processedBatch = 0;

while(processedBatch < unProcessedDataCount)
{
    var processDataChunk = getUnProcessedDataQuery.ToPagedList(processedBatch,50,unProcessedDataCount);
    foreach(var data in processDataChunk)
    {
       //process each Data
       try
       {
          //process data
          data.IsProcessed = true;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       { 
          data.IsProcessed = false
       }
    }

    // update IsProcessed column in database for 50 records
    await BulkUpdateProcessData(processDataChunk); 
    processedBatch = processedBatch + 50;
}

public statis class PagingExtensions
{
   public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> sourcce, int skip,int pageSize,int totalCount)
   {
       pageSize = Math.Max(pageSize,1);
       
       var data = new List<T>();
       data.AddRange(source.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).toList());
       return new PagedList<T>(data,skip,pageSize,totalCount);
    }
}

public class PagedList<T> : List<T>,IPagedList<T>
{
   public PagedList(IList<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int? totalCount = null)
   {
      pageSize  = Math.Max(pageSize,1)
      data.AddRange(totalCount!=null ? source : source.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).toList());
    }
}
```

How can I fix this pagination issue?

**Note:** this is a background service which is getting the data in chunks and processing it.

Comment: `catch(Exception ex)` <-- _wat_

Comment: Your code is conflating `skip` (_offset_) with `pageIndex`: `skip` is defined as `pageIndex * pageSize`. You're passing the wrong values when you call  `return new PagedList<T>(data,skip,pageSize,totalCount);` (and this is why named arguments are essential to avoid careless bugs like these)

Comment: @Dai I agree the arguments are named wrongly but the code is working fine when I take BulkUpdateProcessData outside of While loop and bulkupdate the "ProcessData" at the end. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello, you are saying that last 17 records does not get updated - and you are pointing at `BulkUpdateProcessData`. You didn't posted what this method does. Your loop looks ok. I runned it locally and it pushing all 167 records through that method - but I guess internals is causing the issue

Comment: @jgasiorowski It takes a list nd updates IList<ProcessData> with IsProcessed as true/false in the database.

Comment: maybe you should consider paginate with the PK ? `Where(p => p.ProcessDataId > lastProcessDataId).Take(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder how it does update that much - since you are updating `IsProcessed` in the `BulkUpdateProcessData` the next `getUnProcessedDataQuery.ToPagedList` should ignore bunch of unprocessed data. Just take the 50 records with query and that's it:

```cs
var processDataChunk = await getUnProcessedDataQuery.Take(50).ToListAsync();
```

**UPD**

To filter out already tried items you can add filtering by max processed ID:

```cs
var maxId = int.MinValue; // or nullable int
while(...)
{
    var processDataChunk = await getUnProcessedDataQuery
        .Where(p => p.ProcessDataId > maxId)
        .Take(50)
        .ToListAsync();
    maxId = ...; // find max in chunk
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I should remove the Skip method from my pagination class ?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow I would recommend not to use this Pagination class at all for this case.

Comment: This works fine but the only problem is that there is an issue in processing ProcessDataId = 1 then in the catch section I am setting IsProcessed = false so in the next batch I am getting ProcessDataId = 1 again. I don't want that. Can you guide how can I prevent that? Please see the update in my question

Comment: Upvoted for all your kind efforts towards helping me. Just a quick question: why use int.MinValue and not just 0?  Wanted to know for my understanding

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow just a habit. Cause you can't have integer which is less)

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow the suggested approach does not work for you?

Comment: New approach is working fine. Thank you so much for your time and kind efforts towards helping me. Appreciate it